# Possible mistake in an exercise of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I believe I have found a flaw in an exercise in a book of analysis written in Portuguese, namely, Curso de Análise vol.1, Elon Lima, 15th edition, and would like to pick your brain about it.
The exercise is the following:
[image]

Now, this exercise is big and I do not want to translate it fully, for the mistake here can be found by comparing mainly two equations, which are highlighted above.

So, let $t_{n,m}$ be a set of non negative numbers ordered so that $n,m$ may assume any natural value, let $x_n$ be a sequence so that $\lim(x_n)=0$. There are other conditions imposed on $t_{n,m}$ which are not relevant here.

Let $y_n$ be the sequence as on the first highlighted equation.

Now, it seems evident to me that:

(1) |$y_n$|=$t_{n,1}$|$x_1$|+$t_{n,2}$|$x_2$|+...+$t_{n,n}$|$x_n$|, since the set $t_{n,m}$ has only nonnegative numbers.

(2) It is impossible that |$y_n$|<$t_{n,1}$|$x_1$|+$t_{n,2}$|$x_2$|+...+$t_{n,n}$|$x_n$|, as it is implied in the second highlighted text. Again, it does not matter the value of $p$ in the highlighted text, it is some number between 1 and $n$.

Comment: The triangle inequality says that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$.  If $a \geq 0$ sure you can write the latter as $a +|b|$, but the $\leq$ still needs to be there.  Consider greatly negative $b$.

Comment: of course, i did not see it, thank you for the help